# Regex to match exact string between two delimeters

Tags: php, regex

I need to match from a string like the following:

```
27,B661|27,071315S|27,B2843|2,355516|27,ASB844|27,H994|28,073126|
```

Basically, I want to match the exact text after a comma but before a vertical bar. So 'B661' will match. 'B66' alone will NOT match. Can't seem to figure this out!

Comment: That's nice. Good luck with that. Did you have a programming question? This site is for questions, not a place to dump your to-do list or (lack of) progress reports.

Comment: Something like `\,[^\|]`. Adjust it further.

Comment: Just `explode` it.

Comment: Confused...isn't this a valid programming question about how to construct a regex? With a question title formed as if to help someone else in the future searching for a similar problem? Not sure where all down votes are coming from.

Comment: @LukeB post what you have tried, what you expected, what your results were.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Either `explode()` it twice(!) as @Wiktor said;

```
<?php

$string = "27,B661|27,071315S|27,B2843|2,355516|27,ASB844|27,H994|28,073126|";

$arr = explode("|", $string);
foreach ($arr as $item) {
    list($key, $value) = explode(",", $item);
    echo "$key: $value\n";
}

?>
```

Or with a regex like:

```
(?<=,)\w+(?=|)
```

See [**a demo on regex101.com**](https://regex101.com/r/qL4qD3/1).

Comment: Thanks for the answer...tried using explode before I posted, but wanted to find something cleaner. Actually ended up using strpos.

Comment: *"tried using explode before I posted"* -- Next time, please include what you tried in the original post.